# How to show that λ is an eigenvalue of D by finding a corresponding eigenfunction

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Define the *differentiation operator* $D$ to be the transformation
$D : C_\infty(\mathbb R)\to C_\infty(\mathbb R)$ given by $D( f ) = f'$.

How can I show that every real number $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $D$ by finding a corresponding eigenfunction and what will be the dimension of its eigenspace

Comment: Is your problem how to find a solution to $f'=\lambda f$, or how to see that finding such a solution would imply that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue?

Comment: Actually it is both I need the first part of your question to understand the second part of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** For a given number $\lambda$, consider $f(x)=e^{\lambda x}$, which is a vector in your vector space. Why is this an eigenvector? What is the associated eigenvalue?

Answer (score 0):

$D(f)$ = $f^{'}$ = $\lambda$.${e^{\lambda.x}}$ = $\lambda. f$  hence $f(x)$ = ${e^{\lambda.x}}$ is in  the eigenspace  {${f | D(f)= \lambda.x}$}, the eigenspace  = Span {${e^{\lambda.x}}$} and $dim$ ( such eigenspace) = 1

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Am I right?